# Call id textbox when use autocomplete jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, textbox, jquery-autocomplete

I have a textbox use autocomplete, when i load ajax to call textbox with same id from another page, autocomplete not usable in this textbox.

Example:

> $(document).ready(function() {
>
> ```
>   $("#myid").autocomplete("search.php", {
>       width: 200,
>       matchContains: true,
>       selectFirst: false
>   });
> });
> ```

textbox1 with id="myid" ready when page load first <--  autocomple use well

textbox2 with same id="myid", just appear when i call ajax to load from another page,textbox2 will repalce textbox1 <--- textbox2 can not read function to use autocomple.

Maybe ready(function() just work when page load?

Could write it same named function for insert on event (onkeyup,..) in textbox?

Exp: `input type="text" id="myid" onkeyup="namedfunction('myid')"`  or `onkeyup="namedfunction(this.value)"`?

I don't know why? Anyone please help me?

Thanks!

---

3tgz12

Comment: haven't you get any javascript error..? regarding **myid**..

Answer (score 0):

your page cannot have same ids so you can leverage class here i.e use `class="myid"` instead of `id="myid"` 
and change the code to class selector. hope it will help you

```
$(".myid").autocomplete("search.php", {
      width: 200,
      matchContains: true,
      selectFirst: false
  });
```

Comment: Yes. I tried that way, I even wrote a separate function for each textbox. 

> textbox1 with id="id1", textbox2 with id="id2" and 2 function
> 
> $(".id1").autocomplete , $(".id2").autocomplete

But textbox2 still unreadable autocomplete.

The problem is that when the display textbox2 by call ajax from page containing textbox2, textbox2 will replace textbox1. So the page still unique "myid". But textbox2 unreadable autocomplete.

Anyway thanks for your help !

Comment: try to write autocomplete function  in page containing textbox2 just give a try i am not sure. any how i will look into the issue and get back to you.